# Parse Server Email Template Multiple Languages

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, mailgun

I am using a [Parse Server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) for an app that is offered in different languages. For sending verification and password reset emails I am using the [parse-server-mailgun](https://github.com/sebsylvester/parse-server-mailgun) email adapter. This works great but does not support email templates in different languages. Therefore I am currently including multiple texts in different languages in the same email.

As this does not look very professional, I am looking for a solution to localise the emails.

I thought about building an own email adapter but there is still the problem that the link generated by the server is redirecting to a webpage that must be localised too.

Does anyone have any idea what would be the best approach to get this working?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the email adapter to check a 'locale' property on the user object that I set on signup. The adapter will then serve the desired template based on the users locale. In my case it will use a german template if the locale begins with 'de'.

```
sendVerificationEmail({ link, appName, user }) {
   let locale = user.get('locale');
   let templateName = 'verificationEmail';
   if (locale && locale.startsWith('de')) {
      templateName = 'verificationEmailDE';
   }
   return this._sendMail({
      templateName: templateName,
      link,
      appName,
      user
   });
}
```

Further I attached a script to the public html files like `choose-password.html` to translate the page based on the browser language:

```
  <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      window.onload = function() {
          var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
          if (userLang.startsWith('de')) {
              document.getElementById('label').textContent = "Translated text";
          }
      }
  </script>
```

I hope this answer helps someone with the same problem.